# Why not use Object.prototype.toString() to check plain object in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am a javaScript beginer. When I read redux source code, `utils/isPlainObject.js` has a snippet as follows:

```
export default function isPlainObject(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) return false
  let proto = obj
  while (Object.getPrototypeOf(proto) !== null) {
    proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto)
  }
  return Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === proto
}
```

In my opinion, I may be use simpler code to realize it:

```
function isPlainObject(obj) {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj, null) === '[object Object]'
}
```

So, Why not redux use this realizations ?

Comment: I think your proposition is correct - it does the same thing. However as for "why redux doesn't use it", it might be because simply they measured performance and it turned out in most cases the first one is better. Or they just used it without thinking much. You would need to do a performance check. Or ask them : )

Comment: You might want to read exact specification so you maybe find a difference between the two: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.getprototypeof
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevalue

Answer (score 3):

`typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null`, etc. checks are used because that's most simple way to check if an object is plain that leaves no space for wrong behaviour.

Besides the fact that `Object.prototype.toString` can be overridden and thus affect the code that relies on it, the problem with it is that it doesn't check if an object is plain:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(new class Foo {}, null) === '[object Object]'
```